# How to modify base class properties from sub classes via super.init in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

How to modify base class properties from sub classes via super.init in Swift?

Consider Base class has a property called first name, so i want sub class to add last name and pass it via super.init 
Below is the code

```
class mainClass {
    var firstname : String = "Abhinav"
    init(firstname : String){
        self.firstname = firstname
    }
    func printfirstname(){
        print(firstname)
    }
}
class subClass:mainClass {
var lastname : String

    init(lastname:String){
        self.lastname = lastname
        let name :String = firstname + lastname
        super.init(firstname:name)
    }
    func printname(){
        print(firstname)
    }

}

var subclass = subClass(lastname:"Jha")
subclass.printfirstname()
```

i am getting error " **use of 'self' in property access 'firstname' before super.init initializes self** "

Comment: Recommend you read more about classes and initialization from the Apple Docs. You are very confused

Comment: It would be great, if you would explain, I am getting more confused after reading from docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `firstName` of your super class before it is being initialised. You should call `super.init()` first. It would look something like:

```
init(lastname:String){
    self.lastname = lastname
    super.init(firstname: "Abhinav")
    let name = firstname + lastname
    self.firstname = name
}
```